# Ruby Segmentation fault with FastImage and Taglib

Tags: ruby, taglib-ruby

I'm using [FastImage](https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage) and [TagLib](https://github.com/robinst/taglib-ruby) to manipulate mp3 files and, in this example, to extract a possible image from the tags. It was working like a charm, but for one file it is happening a bug that I don't know how to handle.

```rb
TagLib::MPEG::File.open(input_file_path) do |file|
  tag = file.id3v2_tag
  if tag
    size = tag.frame_list.size
    if size > 0
      cover = tag.frame_list('APIC').first
      if cover
        File.open(original_image, 'w+') do |f|
          f.write(cover.picture)
        end
        FastImage.resize(original_image, 250, 250, :outfile => resized_image)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

On the `FastImage.resize` method it's happening the following error:

> GD Error: gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: Invalid JPEG file structure: two SOI markers /< user path >/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/fastimage_resize-2.0.3/lib/fastimage_resize.rb:90: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000008
>   ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin14]

There is no problem in having an error in the image, because it's uploaded by an user, but I need to rescue this error to give the proper treatment and I'm not finding a way to do this. I want to know if there is a way to rescue this error.

Comment: A segmentation fault is a bug in whatever software's involved here. It's probably worth filing an issue with the library creator if you can reliably reproduce it.